# Getting django-socialregistration and facebook connect working

Tags: django, facebook, registration

Having trouble getting the django-socialregistration app running properly. We were able to get the system working on one of our dev's Django setups with an apache server instead of the development server.

We changed the database settings so that the django development server can run properly on our second development environment and have left all of the other settings the same.

However, when we attempt to use the facebook connect button and then click "Allow" in the pop up, we're taken to a page with the following cryptic message:

```
facebook.html
This is the error template which is shown when a user logs in via Facebook and something goes wrong.
```

Have double checked that the App ID and secret are correct.
Have double checked the correct domain and callback URLs.

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated on how to debug this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't able to get the django-socialregistration app working in the end. Ultimately, went ahead and used the Facebook Javascript SDK: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to guess what the real problem is based on the information you've supplied.

Make sure you understand the process that Facebook goes through to authenticate users. Read Facebook's documentation on the process [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/registration/), particularly under the heading 'Login and Registration Flows'. There's more useful background [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/user_registration/flows/).

One thing I'd check first would be the configuration of the application you registered with Facebook. Does your Django application have the correct application ID and secret? Have you configured your Facebook application with the correct domain and callback URLs?

Is your dev server actually accessible via the internet? Can Facebook post data back to it?

If you go away and try this stuff and let us know what you find, maybe we can help more.

Comment: hi Gareth! Thanks for the help. So, as I mentioned in my original post, the settings are duplicated from my teammate's original development environment and facebook app configurations. The only changes are that he is an apache server instead of the django dev server, which we don't believe should change anything.

Comment: You're right that I didn't try to see if my dev server is accessible via the internet, though. I will try to verify.

Comment: ok, so the server is not accessible via the internet or to facebook; however, Facebook doesn't send any messages to my server. Facebook is sending messages to my client which is receiving some kind of response from facebook. I'm having issue capturing the response with firebug since the window closes after it receives the response. Thanks again for the thoughts, though.